# CSS Invert colors in transparent svg element

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

in my html I have transparent svg circle. I need to invert colors on this svg circle, so I will see black circle with cyan text.

I tried to set `.cursor__inner`'s fill to transparent with filter invert(1) (as you can see it on code snippet), but it didn't work.

```css
.cursor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.cursor__inner {
  fill: transparent;
  filter: invert(1);
}
p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<svg class="cursor" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
  <circle class="cursor__inner" cx="32" cy="32" r="32" />
</svg>
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

I want to make this effect:

[image: effect]

I prefer solution with pure css.

Comment: Inverting transparency is not going to give black (which is the inverse of white) as it's not inverting the alpha channel (opacity) part. Could you describe a bit more what your constraints are - what do you have control over and what don't you have control over? e.g. is there any reason the transparency couldn't instead be white? Can you change any of the CSS/HTML/SVG?

Comment: I can change CSS and HTML.

Comment: I can change SVG too, but I'd rather not change SVG.

Comment: So why not just set fill=black for the SVG and color:cyan for the p? What is the significance of the invert?

Comment: Because, on my site have more colors (red color was only example). See my update - I added image.

Comment: Thank you, that makes it much clearer. Are you looking for mix blend mode or some sort of masking for example?

Comment: Yes, I think it would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of achieving the required result is close to the code given in the question.

The color of the text in the p element is inverted so that the part lying over the circle has the color cyan. The background of the element containing the p and svg (in this snippet's case, the body) has a background of white set so the mix-blend-mode on the text takes the difference of the color (which is now #00ffff = cyan) and white (#ffffff) to take us back to red (#ff0000).

As noted in comments, it's not possible to invert the SVG circle color as it has transparency so will always have that whatever RGB it has inverted so it's filled with a solid color.

```css
body {
  background: white;
  height: 100vh;
}

.cursor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.cursor__inner {
  fill: black;
}

p {
  color: cyan;
  color: red;
  filter: invert(1);
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <svg class="cursor" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <circle class="cursor__inner" cx="32" cy="32" r="32" />
    </svg>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</body>
```

Comment: What would be permissable? You've got to do something to stop the circle being transparent. Different classes can of course set different colors for different instances if required. Is the problem because you need several versions?

Answer (score 0):

Like this? transparent inverted is transparent so i set fill to white. and filter: invert uses %.

filter: invert(1) <- Wrong
filter: invert(100%) <- Right

```css
.cursor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.cursor__inner {
  fill: white;
  z-index: -1;
}
p {
  color: red;
  z-index: 100;
}
.invert {
filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<svg class="cursor invert" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
  <circle class="cursor__inner" cx="32" cy="32" r="32" />
</svg>
<p class="invert">Hello World!</p>
```

Comment: No, I don't want this. See my last edit - I added image.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this.

```css
.cursor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.cursor__inner {
  fill: white;
  filter: invert(100%);
}
p {
  color: red;
  filter: invert(100%);

}
```

```html
<svg class="cursor" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
  <circle class="cursor__inner" cx="32" cy="32" r="32" />
</svg>
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

Comment: No, I don't want this. See my last edit - I added image.